# Is there a real time IIS traffic viewer (or way to programmatically get it via C#)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, logging

I would like to get a feel for the web traffic that I'm having on an IIS box, and was wondering if there is already a good 'real time' IIS tool out there.

Ideally this would something I could apply custom scripting logic to.

Also, is there a way to programmatically (from C#) access that information? It looks like the way to do it is via Performance counters or parsing the IIS log, but surely there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing a real-time IIS/App logging solution using Firebase (see [my blog post for a screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822001940/http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/04/from-azure-to-firebase-could-not.html) of it in action).

It works really well, with us having real-time access to what happens in the live website.

I can post more details there is interest in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Good point, I'll need such thing soon as well.
Quick search gave me [IIS Traffic Monitor](https://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1480) and [this bunch of tools](https://web.software.informer.com/download-web-traffic-analyzer-for-iis/).
Haven't used any of them.

Comment: -1: don't really like answers that are only links, especially since you haven't tried any of those tools.

Comment: Yes but it added value, and those links are valid (first was broken, but I just edited the comment and fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to see traffic in real time, **but not an IIS tool**, try Google Analytics  - it has a real time view of active users on your site. Of course you can also have insight to historical data (over time) so you get a real picture of traffic to your site.

On the other hand, log parsing will be more accurate which you can do programmatically - or even "old school" reporting either via loading your log data into Excel or [SQL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296085)....

Comment: I came here to say this exact thing. Forget IIS, go with Google Analytics.

Comment: Google Analytics (GA) is not what I want. They don't work with Webservices, require me to add a bit of JS to all websites, add a call to google servers to get JS and rely on the brower to render javascript from external domains

Comment: Then you'll have to work with log files to give you visibility into all the request traffic you have on your box (css, images, script files, etc).   Depending on the size of your log files, it's probably best to load the data to some db.